# How to draw a ellipse which passes two given points and is tangent to two given line?

Tags: spheres, geometric-construction, cross-sections

I was trying to draw Dandelin spheres using an ellipse. Then, I had to construct an ellipse that is tangent to two lines and passes two given points on the angle bisector of the two lines.

I attempted to draw a two-line tangent ellipse and dilate it to the points given.

But it didn't work, like below:

[image]

Now, how should I deal with it..?

BTW, this is my current progress with drawing the Dandelin spheres.

[image]

Comment: It's *ellipse*, not "eclipse".

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry, my English is not that good... :(

Comment: Typically you need 5 constraints.  Here you have only 4 (2 pts, 2 lines).  Anyway, there are lots of sources on this topic.  Try https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2014volume14/FG201431.pdf

Comment: The "double contact" case 10.1 in the paper might be what you want if you are depicting spheres and circles in contact with a cone.